# Why does Resharper tell me there is a possible NullReferenceException?

Tags: c#, resharper, rider

I switched the Value Analysis Mode in Rider to Pessimistic to highlight every "Possible NullReferenceException" and in the example below, I have a warning on the "Languages[0]" part and I don't understand why since I initialize my collection right after declaring it.

It should not be null then.

I just tested on an empty project and I have the same warning.

```
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace ClassLibrary1
{
    public class Class1
    {
        public static string Current => Languages[0];

        public static readonly List<string> Languages = new List<string>
        {
            "en"
        };
    }
}
```

Is it a mistake made by ReSharper or did I missed something ?

Thanks.

Comment: I don't get this warning. What version of R# are you using?

Comment: I don't know how to get R# version on Rider (OS X). My Rider version is 2019.3 if that is relevant.

Comment: Mine is 2019.3.1, but I don't know if that's really going to make a difference.

Comment: That's not what Resharper warns about though - not without using [CanBeNull] attributes anyway. Resharper WILL warn if it thinks that you are dereferencing something that it thinks IS null, however.

Comment: @MatthewWatson - right... that would be an `IndexOutOfRange`.

Comment: @cdauphin Can you post a compilable repro console app?

Comment: @MatthewWatson Do you happen to know what difference the setting to "pessimistic" may play a role here?

Comment: Yes, pessimistic will increase the number of warnings.

Comment: @MatthewWatson Thanks. Then what I was thinking of cannot be the case here.

Comment: @MatthewWatson I edited the question with a complete class from an empty project I just created. I also tried to update & invalidate cache but I still have the warning.

Comment: I also get this warning when I turn on pessimistic analysis. It's a false warning for the code as written, though, because it is not possible for `Current` to be null when accessed from user code outside the class. (`'Languages` is readonly, so it can't be changed to non-null.)

Answer (score 1):

I think static properties are evaluated in order of appearance. Try to flip them in order to have first "Languages" and then "Current".

Comment: That's not the case for this code, because `Languages ` is a field that will be initialised before it is possible to access `Current`, which is a property.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
public static class Program
{
    public static readonly string Foo = Current;

    public static string Current => Languages[0];

    public static readonly List<string> Languages = new List<string>
    {
        "en"
    };

    public static void Main()
    {
        Console.WriteLine(Foo);
    }
}
```

[SharpLab](https://sharplab.io/#v2:C4LgTgrgdgPgAgJgIwFgBQcAMACOSAsA3OogMzoDe62NupuSAbNmAKYCGAJgPZQA2ATwY4AYt27YAvNgDCEMGyjBiaarTj08zPDjkLWSqQD5sAGXZQA5hHaXWAZwDamALoq1NDQ2ZsuvQWYAlvbAADw6JuZWNnb2UthQrADuQSHhSJhGHthUaLT52ABEBoXZAL7ueeoICNm5BepIAJwAFGLcAJQq+WXoZUA=)

Static members are initialized in the order they're declared. `Foo` is initialized before `Languages` is assigned, and so you see a `NullReferenceException`.

I guess that Resharper's being very pessimistic here, and only considering `Current` in isolation, regardless of whether there's actually another static member that might access it before `Languages` is initialised.

---

You could also have something diabolical like this, where the construction of `Languages` causes something to access `Program.Current`:

```
public static class Program
{
    public static string Current => Languages[0].Value;
    public static readonly List<Language> Languages = new List<Language>() { new Language() };

    public static void Main()
    {
        Console.WriteLine(Current);
    }
}

public class Language
{
    public string Value { get; } = Program.Current;
}
```

(It's a silly example, but it shows that it's perhaps harder for Resharper to prove that nothing accesses `Program.Current` before `Program`'s type initializer has finished running, than you might expect).

Comment: Yes, it's a false positive warning from Resharper, at least for the code the OP posted.